# How do I assign a char pointer with cin?

Tags: c++

So basically when I try to do this

```
char* inputFileName;
cout<<  "Filename: "; cin>>*inputFileName;
```

it lets me input the filename but when I press enter I get an unhandled exception error. Any ideas?

edit also if I try

```
char* inputFileName;
cout<<  "Filename: "; cin>>inputFileName;
```

I get a debug assertion failed when I try to run it.

Comment: `inputFileName` is just a (dangling) pointer, it doesn't provide any storage for your string; you have to allocate some memory for the string, as for now you're just telling to `cin` to write the read characters at a random (potentially invalid) memory location. Study C strings on a book *before* messing with them.

Comment: @MatteoItalia is right. Also, you should not be dereferencing `inputFileName`.

Comment: The proper way is to just not use a `char *`. That's what `std::string` is for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to pass in the pointer, not the dereferenced pointer, and have allocated memory for the char *

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    const size_t BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
    char inputFileName[BUFFER_SIZE];
    cout << "Filename: ";
    cin >> setw(BUFFER_SIZE) >> inputFileName;
    cout << inputFileName << endl;
}
```

Another option besides `char inputFileName[BUFFER_SIZE];` is

```
char *inputFileName = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

and later

```
delete [] inputFileName;
```

Comment: delete [] (although std::string is really the right answer, imo)

Comment: I think using string instead of array of chars could be simpler

Comment: Agreed, I would use std::string, but I was trying to answer the question as asked.

Comment: It is answering it imo. The OP needs to read in a series of characters and that's what `cin >> someString;` does (though for a file name, `getline` would probably be better). `cin >> someCharArray;` is prone to buffer overflows. If we focused on the most specific question being asked for every question, XY questions would end up terribly and a lot of people would miss out on the fact that there's a much easier and safer way to do what they're trying to do.

Comment: This is dangerous! Guaranteed stack smashing vulnerability (heap smashing if ``new`` is used) for untrusted input. One should at least do ``stream >> std::setw(1024)`` rsp. ``stream.width(1024)``, but I highly recommend using ``std::string`` because it is harder to misuse.

Comment: Fixed the vulnerability. I don't like the explicit ``delete []`` much because unlike ``unique_ptr<char[]>`` it lacks exception safety, but it's at least safe here because iostream operations, by default, don't throw.

Answer (score 4):

Try using this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *inputFileName = new char[50];
    cout << "Filename: ";
    cin >> inputFileName;
    cout << inputFileName << endl;
    /* .... */
    delete [] inputFileName;
}
```