# Saving string to class attribute using character pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, io

I'm having difficulty trying to take in inputs using cin, saving them to a few variables, and then constructing a class. When I put in the first input, instead of waiting for the next input, the program loop infinitely and keeps displaying the prompt over and over.

The class is:

```
class person {
public:
    char *name;
    char *email;
    int phone;
    // constructor that uses the parameters to initialize the class properties
    person(char *cName, char *cEmail, int iPhone) {
        name = new (char[32]);  // acquiring memory for storing name
        email = new (char[32]);     // acquiring memory for storing email
        strcpy(name, cName);        // initialize name
        strcpy(email, cEmail);  // initialize email
        phone = iPhone;         // initialize phone
    }
    virtual ~person() {
        delete[] name;
        delete[] email;
    }
};
```

And the input and constructor call is as follows:

```
char* nameIn = new (char[32]);  // acquiring memory for storing name
char* emailIn = new (char[32]);
int iPhoneIn;

cout << "Enter name, email, and phone:\n";

    cin >> *nameIn;
    cin >> *emailIn;
    cin >> iPhoneIn;

person* newPerson = new person(nameIn, emailIn, iPhoneIn); //create node
```

Comment: You should use `std::string` instead of C-style strings.

Comment: Check this one (similar): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329074/how-do-i-assign-a-char-pointer-with-cin

Comment: I would use that, but the point of this assignment is to get us to transition from C to C++ and unfortunately it requires that the person constructor take in character pointers instead of just using the string.

Comment: @SJD Thank you. That link had exactly what I was looking for. But I'm having trouble understanding why we put the cin into the pointer instead of the deferenced pointer. Right now, nameIn and emailIn are just pointers to these new character arrays. Don't we want to dereference the pointers so that it saves the input into the character arrays? EDIT: Thought it through, and I understand it now. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix/improve your code in a few ways.

First, we'll start with the obviously wrong. When you're reading in input from cin, don't dereference (call the * operator on) your character pointers (**char***). cin should receive a **char***, not a **char**. If you pass it a **char**, it will only write the first character you input. Therefore you need to pass it a **char*** if you want to input a string.

```
cin >> *nameIn; // this should be: cin >> nameIn;
cin >> *emailIn; // this should be cin >> emailIn;
```

Run this snippet with and without the suggested change to see what I mean:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()  {
    cout << "Input a string: ";
    char * c = new(char[200]);
    cin >> *c; // only writes the first input character. Change to: cin >> c;
    cout << "You input: " << c; // prints the first input character then garbage
    delete[](c);
    return 0;
}
```

Second, don't represent phone numbers with an integer. `int phone;` won't work for standard 10-digit phone numbers. On most platforms, the maximum value that can be represented with integers is about 2.1 billion. Most 10-digit numbers are greater than 2.1 billion. Use an array of characters instead. Adjust your input method accordingly.

Third, don't needlessly dynamically allocate memory. If you know from the start that all names will fit in 32 characters, then declare them as such.

```
char *name; // change to char name[32];
char *email; // change to char email[32];
```

This will both run faster and save you the pain of having to free allocated memory. You'll be able to completely remove the destructor.